# REST API support by survey monkey

Tags: surveymonkey

I am planning to do a survey  using survey monkey. I will require API support to automatically pull responses from your datasource. I looked into https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/get_responses/ and it looks like I need to use services like curl to extract data. It also looks like I can extract data in json format. And the data that is extracted using get_responses api, returns only ids.

So my questions are:
1. Do you support REST APIs to download data? 
2. Can I download data in csv format?
3. Can I download actual responses with questions and not just ids? What APIs will be return survey, questions asked and user responses?
3. Can you send me an example format of how data will look when downloaded using the APIs?
5. Finally, with $26/month subscription for one month, will I get API support? Is the API support available for free subscription?

Thanks!!

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, a site for programming questions and answers, not Survey Monkey's support. You will have to talk to them directly. There's a developer support E-Mail address right next to where you (probably) found the link to Stack Overflow: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/

Comment: True. But when I talked with Surveymonkey customer care they asked me to post any api related question in stack overflow tagging surveymonkey. Hence this question.

Comment: Then I'm afraid Survey Monkey's customer care gave you bad advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SurveyMonkey does have a REST API

You can get all responses (just ids) doing:

```
GET /surveys/{survey_id}/responses
```

See: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses

You can get the details and all answers to questions for a specific response by ID doing:

```
GET /responses/{response_id}/details
```

See: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#responses-id

Or you can do this all at once by doing

```
GET /surveys/{id}/responses/bulk
```

See: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk

Answer (score 0):

1. Answered by akand074.
2. We only support JSON at this time.
3. You'll have to make a separate GET to /v3/surveys/{survey_id}/details to get the survey details, and then map it to the response data.
4. The format, along with response data examples can be found [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses-bulk).
5. You'll have to contact api-support@surveymonkey.com to find out.

Comment: someone from survey monkey has already contacted me. Thanks!!